# Android Java Emulator . . WARNING: Data partition already in use. Changes will not persist

Tags: android, eclipse

I am trying to run an Android project in Eclipse(Android 2.3.3, on a Windows 7 64-bit machine), but I run in to the following error (on console window). This worked a couple of hours ago but now does not and I don't think I changed anything major. Would appreciate any help I can to fix this issue please

```
[2012-09-02 17:38:33 - mapviewballoons.Main] Starting incremental Pre Compiler: Checking resource changes.
[2012-09-02 17:38:33 - mapviewballoons.Main] Nothing to pre compile!
[2012-09-02 17:38:33 - samplemap] Refreshing resource folders.
[2012-09-02 17:38:35 - Emulator] WARNING: Data partition already in use. Changes will not persist!
[2012-09-02 17:38:35 - Emulator] WARNING: SD Card image already in use: C:\Users\MACHINEOVA\.android\avd\MAPAPP1.avd/sdcard.img
[2012-09-02 17:38:35 - Emulator] WARNING: Cache partition already in use. Changes will not persist!
```

Answer (score 7):

Same problem also i have faced.

I deleted My emulator and create a new emulator.

It's working fine for me.

Answer (score 6):

If none of the previous answers have worked try navigating to the folder mentioned in the error message (in your case C:\Users\MACHINEOVA.android\avd\MAPAPP1.avd/) and (on Windows) there will be several folders whose names end in .lock, delete those and restart your emulator.

Answer (score 2):

Please try to check the "Wipe user data" in the AVD and run it. If that won't help end adb process ( alt-ctrl-del --> start task manager and in the process tab find adb.exe to close it). Restart eclipse and it should work then.

Comment: Where do I find "Wipe user data" in the AVD? How do I get to it from Eclipse?

Comment: in Eclispe: go to 'Window' --> 'AVD Manager' Then choose your avd and click start. You will see few checkboxes. Unchecked everything and keep checked only 'Wipe user data'

Comment: I did check there but I don't see a "Wipe User Data" checkbox. I do see a "Snapshot Enabled" checkbox which is currently unchecked.

Comment: Normally you should have 3 checkboxes: 1. Wipe user data, 2. Launch from snapshot 3. Save to snapshot. I would recommened to restart eclipse and kill adb process as I mentioned earlier. It also happens to me few times and I fixed it by following the steps I'm describing here now.

Comment: OK I know why you don't see rest of the checkboxes. You have clicked edit instead of start. Please click start on your AVD

Comment: Where else can I look for the "Wipe user data" Check box please?

Comment: As I said in my previous comment. "Snapshot Enabled" that you can see, appears when you click "edit" Please click "start" then different window pops up where you have already mentioned checkboxes available

Comment: I was able to check the box, and restart but I am still observing the same issue.

Comment: have you killed adb service as I mentioned about eariler?

Comment: I killed it a couple of times and did restart Eclipse

Comment: Try to go to DDMS perspective and click on the down arrow next to the screen capture camera icon and select reset adb from the dropdown menu. It is in the device window on the left in DDMS perspective.

Comment: Window--> Open perspective --> DDMS

Comment: I have shutdown adb process via DDMS. What do I do now? I tried to run the project again but the same error comes up.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16170/discussion-between-kobojunkie-and-marcin-s)

Answer (score 2):

I fixed the same problem by first making sure that no adb.exe process is running in the process tab on task manager.

Then make sure that AVD(avd.exe on windows) is not being invoked either as a GUI or from any teminal.(avd.exe -avd ).

NOTE- Checking on "Wipeout user data" will not help in any way fixing this problem.
Also deleting your avd is also not a wise solution to fix this problem.

Answer (score 0):

just delete all the configured emulaters u have now.
create a new one using AVD(android vertual device) manager in Eclipse toolbar
try with normal procedure
that will work fine form me.

Answer (score 0):

Kill the adb process,and restart your eclipse

Answer (score 0):

Delete *.lock directories at .android\avd\your.avd\ , restart emulator

This happened to me after incorrect closing of emulator. I didnt closed it but shut down the computer with emulator running. Direct emulator exiting will help.