# Wont run android apps when I launch my emulator from snapshot

Tags: android, eclipse, adt, snapshot

If I launch my android emulator from snapshot it wont let me run the apps I'm working on. Is there a way to fix this? If I launch from snapshot it launches really fast which is why I'm asking if there's a way to do this. If I wipe the user data and launch from scratch it takes FOR EVER to load, which has alway driven me crazy!!

These are the error messages I always get:

```
[2015-03-02 13:38:28 - Emulator] WARNING: Data partition already in use. Changes will not persist!
[2015-03-02 13:38:28 - Emulator] WARNING: SD Card image already in use: C:\Users\Ben\.android\avd\ANDROID.avd/sdcard.img
[2015-03-02 13:38:28 - Emulator] ko:Snapshot storage already in use: C:\Users\Ben\.android\avd\ANDROID.avd/snapshots.img
```

Answer (score 0):

This has already been answered in the past on SO - [Android Java Emulator . . WARNING: Data partition already in use. Changes will not persist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12240436/android-java-emulator-warning-data-partition-already-in-use-changes-will-n). Try deleting the *.lock directories and restart the emulator. This should remove the lock on the SD Card images. Do not wipe the user data, the Android Emulator will then take longer to start.

Comment: Hmm.. I just tried that twice and now when it loads the snapshot it's unresponsive. Nothing works. It displays the last screen I was on but I can't do anything.